# Android ScrollView fill 60%

Tags: java, android, xml

In my android app I like to fill the scrollView to 60% of the screen.. and inside the scrollView I need to display textviews... For that I wrote the following code.. but the scrollView is filling 100% .. what  change I need to do for attaining 60%... I need to display this textviews inside a relative layout if it is possible..

Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

     >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/lLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="7"
         android:background="@drawable/bwt1">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="PYNo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="CPin" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="What 2014 brings for you...."
            android:textSize="16dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Prediction for :" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
            android:text="D.O.B :" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Your Personal Year Number : " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Prediction for your Personal Year will be displayed here..." />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Your Current Pinnacle : " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView12"
            android:text="/" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="yyyy" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
            android:text="/" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView14"
            android:text="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="mm" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView9"
            android:text="dd" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="The Prediction for Current Pinnacle will be displayed here." />

        </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/rLayout4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"></RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set the height property of scrollview to 0dip

Comment: Y.. Mahmoud.. I didn't see u in my life.. and I think I didn't do any harm to you at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, i re-organized some of your component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bwt1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="7" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="PYNo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="CPin" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="What 2014 brings for you...."
            android:textSize="16dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="Prediction for :" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
            android:text="D.O.B :" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Your Personal Year Number : " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Prediction for your Personal Year will be displayed here..." />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="Your Current Pinnacle : " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView12"
            android:text="/" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
            android:text="yyyy" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
            android:text="/" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView14"
            android:text="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="mm" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView9"
            android:text="dd" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
            android:padding="15dip"
            android:text="The Prediction for Current Pinnacle will be displayed here." />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rLayout4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="3" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Setting Orientation Property of the LinearLayout to Vertical. As the default orientation is horizontal.

Comment: Im am tryig.. just a min